# Custom required error message

Tags: validation, angular

I have `required` in my input element and I want to set custom error message there.

this works:
`oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('custom error')"`

But I want to read that error message from resources which is in `json` file. I'm using `i18n` and [ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate) which works fine if I'll do:
`<span>{{'General.EmptySearch' | translate }}</span>` it displays my error message.

so If I'll do that:

`oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('{{'General.EmptySearch' | translate }}')"`

it says

> Binding to event property 'oninvalid' is disallowed for security reasons, please use (invalid)=...
>   If 'oninvalid' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module.

ok I'll change it. I'm doing that:

`(invalid)="this.setCustomValidity('{{'General.EmptySearch' | translate }}')"`

error is:

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 24 in [this.setCustomValidity('{{'General.EmptySearch' | translate }}')]

What's wrong?

Here is my form:

int `.ts` file

```
searchval: FormGroup;
ngOnInit() {
        this.searchval = new FormGroup({
            Search: new FormControl('')
        });
}
```

and html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchval)" [formGroup]="searchval">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" required formControlName="Search" placeholder="{{ 'General.Search' | translate }}">
                    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Interesting. Before reading your question, I had no idea there was an [`invalid` DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid). So you're watching the "invalid" event and you set the error message when this event happens, correct? If so, I've never seen things done that way with Angular. Errors are typically displayed by watching the field's `errors` property.

Comment: @AngularFrance yes I'm trying to do that. can you show me another way to do that? I don't want to display to the user default error message.

Comment: And you are using Template-Driven Forms, correct? (NOT model-driven forms)

Comment: @AngularFrance I've updated my question

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you are using the **model-driven** form syntax.

Check out the [official doc on form validation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html). It shows how to do form validation the proper way. It ALSO shows how to have validation messages in your code (vs in your template), which is what your question was about. Once your validation messages are in your code, you'll have no problem translating them.

Side note: I'm really curious why you wanted to validate your fields watching the `(invalid)` DOM event. I've never seen it done that way.